# React JS state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-state

I am fetching all of the documents in a collection for firebase cloud firestore. I am using useEffect hook to call a function that fetches all the documents and then set the state with an array of new documents but the state doesn't seem to be updating.

This is the code that fetches and updates the state:

```
const fetchBlogs = () => {
        db.collection('blogs').get().then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            setBlogs([...blogs,{
              title:doc.data().title,
              imgURL: doc.data().imgURL,
              desc: doc.data().desc
            }])
          });
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchBlogs();
    },[]);
```

And this is the code that renders the blogs:

```
{
  blogs && blogs.map(blog=>{
    return(
      <Article
         key={blog.title}
         title={blog.title}
         imgurl = {blog.imgURL}
         desc={blog.desc}
       />
    )
  })
}
```

This is how the result currently looks like:
[image]

Comment: your code doesn't seem much problem. Please do two things to debug. 1) put your fetch implementation inside `useEffect`, don't call as a function, because i suspect you put the implementation in the wrong place.  2) put a console.log inside `.then(queryS => { `. This way you know if this call has been success.

Comment: First, instead of setting the state for each object, map the objects to an array of objects in the format you need, and then do setBlogs just once with the result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```js
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
  setBlogs([...blogs,{
    title: doc.data().title,
    imgURL: doc.data().imgURL,
    desc: doc.data().desc
  }])
});
```

to

```js
setBlogs(
  querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
    title: doc.data().title,
    imgURL: doc.data().imgURL,
    desc: doc.data().desc
  }))
);
```

Calling `setBlogs()` multiple times and referencing `blogs` from the closure is going to fail. The reference to `blogs` from the stale closure does not update each time you call `setBlogs()`, so the series of state updates will only render the last document iterated in your snapshot, the way you currently have it written.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please elaborate on what you mean... I really did;t get why mine doesn't work and yours does

Answer (score 1):

Updating `state` in `forEach` does not guarantee the state updates. Generate the data first and update the state `state` later. You can read [these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914782/why-doesnt-the-react-usestate-hook-work-in-a-for-loop) for more information about running `setState` inside loops

```
const fetchBlogs = () => { // You can also move this inside `useEffect` incase if it's not reused. 
  db.collection('blogs').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    const querySnapshots = [] 
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const { title, imgURL, desc } = doc.data()
      querySnapshots.push({ title, imgURL, desc })
    });
    setBlogs([...blogs, ...querySnapshots])
  });
  
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetchBlogs();
},[]);
```

Comment: `querySnapshot` is not an array and does not have a `map` method.

Comment: well, he didn't mentioned that

Comment: then declare an array and push the results to the new array.

Comment: OP said they were using firebase. You should have looked up the relevant reference documentation yourself if you didn't know what `querySnapshot` was.

Comment: I don't  know how firebase `firebase` works , All I can see list, at least you should have mention that. Anyway, update the code, check now

Comment: Thanks, @Naren... The link to the other question was really helpful. Now it makes sense why my code wasn't working